# unable to call a method in a class from conditional statement

Tags: php

The issue is that for some odd reason my code to call a method is not calling the method, this method is locked(). Here is my class:

```
class login 
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $fails;
    public $ip;
    public $sqlObject;


    public function sqlVerify() {
      $user=$this->username;
      $pass=$this->password;
      $sqlObject=$this->sqlObject;
      $fails=$this->fails;

      if($fails >= 4) { $this->locked(); }

      $query=mysqli_query($sqlObject, 
       "SELECT 1 FROM tbl_users 
        WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'");
       if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
           return "1";
       }else{
           return "0";
       }
    }

    private function locked() {
        return "For security, this account has been locked. Contact support.";
    }

}
```

the value of fails = 9 at this time, still no call.. ?

Comment: you cannot  call a private method outside of class. Please try to learn oop concepts first .

Comment: if you want to call function outside of call you have to make it public .

Comment: Also: This wont do anything `if($fails >= 4) { $this->locked(); }` as `lock()` returns a string and you dont do anthing with it

Comment: try `if($fails >= 4) { return $this->locked(); }`

Comment: do you have any error ?

Comment: @HassanALi He is using private method in same class so no issue for that. No need to make it public.

Comment: How do you know that the query worked? You don't check for errors that I can see? example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with below code:

```
public function sqlVerify() {
  $user=$this->username;
  $pass=$this->password;
  $sqlObject=$this->sqlObject;
  $fails=$this->fails;

  if($fails >= 4) { return $this->locked(); } // You need to put return statement here also for returning from this function.

  $query=mysqli_query($sqlObject, 
   "SELECT 1 FROM tbl_users 
    WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'");
   if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
       return "1";
   }else{
       return "0";
   }
}

private function locked() {
    return "For security, this account has been locked. Contact support.";
}
```